# Adding non-indexable fields to the document in lucene - Field.Index deprecated

Tags: lucene

What is the best way to add fields to a document now that Field.Index is deprecated.

Here is what I am doing and what most example online suggest:

```
doc.add(new Field("id", dbID, Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED_NO_NORMS));
```

What is the new recommended way to set Index properties on Fields with Field.Index going away?

Comment: What version of Lucene are you using?

Comment: I am using Lucene 4.6.0. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `org.apache.lucene.document.StoredField` for the fields that you don’t want to index.
Refer 
http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/StoredField.html
to know about the various available constructors. 
example:

```
StoredField strField = new StoredField("id", bag.getId());
```

Hope it helps.